# NGINX ignore hash css file and fetch any css that exists

Tags: css, nginx, browser-cache

I'm cache-busting with hashed css files (app-123456.css). The css file requests are proxied to a cdn with nginx. I need to keep the files statically named on the cdn, as there is a requirement to allow the customer to modify some css and re-upload the file. How can I pass the hashed file request to cdn and return the statically named file? For example a request to app-123456.css would return app.css, if it existed on the cdn. I'm trying to use try files but have been unsuccessful. Will cache-busting still work in this scenario, if the returned file is statically named? Thanks for any help.

```
location ~* (.+)\.(?:\d+)\.(css)$ {
  try_files $uri $1.$2 @styles;
}

location @styles {
  autoindex on;
  proxy_pass http://[url].net; # needs to go to http://[url].net/styles/
}
```

***EDIT***

```
location ~* (.+)-(?:\d+)\.(css)$ {
  try_files $uri $1.$2 @styles;
}

location @styles {
  autoindex on;
  rewrite ^(.+)-(?:\d+)\.(css)$ /styles$1.$2 break;
  proxy_pass http://[url].net; # needs to go to http://[url].net/styles/
}
```

***Fixed***

```
^(.+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\.(css)$
```

Comment: That initial dot in your regular expression should be a hyphen? i.e. `^(.+)-(?:\d+)\.(css)$` So, do you need to add a `rewrite...break` in the `location @styles` block? e.g. `rewrite ^(.+)-(?:\d+)\.(css)$ /styles$1.$2 break;`

Comment: Thanks, I updated per your suggestion but no luck. Am I missing anything?

Comment: My fault. The example name app-123456.css was not accurate as the file name hash is alphanumeric. Thank you so much!

Comment: @RichardSmith, post as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the URI within the named `location` before passing it upstream with `proxy_pass`. This can be accomplished using a `rewrite...break` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

For example, using your updated regular expression:

```
location ~* ^(.+)\-(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)\.(css)$ {
    try_files $uri $1.$2 @styles;
}
location @styles {
    rewrite ^(.+)\-(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)\.(css)$ /styles$1.$2 break;
    proxy_pass http://...;
}
```

---

The above solution basically applies the same regular expression to the URI twice, which seems inefficient and redundant.

If the `/styles/` URI prefix is unique to the upstream server, you could perform the translation in the original `try_files` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
location ~* ^(.+)\-(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)\.(css)$ {
    try_files $uri $1.$2 /styles$1.$2$is_args$args;
}
location ^~ /styles/ {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://...;
}
```

The `^~` operator give the prefix `location` a high precedence (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details) and the `internal` directive prevents the URI from being directly accessible (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) for details).